# Joomla 2.5 home page aliases

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I want to access my website front page via aliases: `http://mysite.com/some_alias_one` and `http://mysite.com/some_alias_two`. Later I want to take `some_alias_one`(as well as `some_alias_two`) parameter in code and proceed further actions with it. In this case I do not need any redirection. If visitor comes with alias `http://mysite.com/some_alias_one`, so he must stay in home page with this alias without redirection. So then in my code I will check is user using alias_one or alias_two and depending to it I will do further actions (for example show some text or modules and etc).

So any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, there is a somewhat simple answer. Simply make 2 menu items that point to the same thing with different aliases. Since the menu items have different aliases, they will have different item IDs and you can assign different modules to each one. You can customize each page based on the modules you add to the page.

The only issue you will have is when a use goes to http://mysite.com - you will need to create a redirect that sends the user to one of the 2 aliases you have created. Either that or one of the 2 menu items will need to be set as the default.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking a bit complicated about all this thing. But menu items is what I actually really need.